# Esconder Menu Tray Icon

Tags: c#, wpf

Criei um menu para o meu `TrayIcon`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém caso o usuário não selecione uma opção ele ainda fica visível.
Alguém saberia como posso esconder caso o usuário clique fora da área do menu?

Eis o código que estou utilizando paracriar o menu:

```
System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon iconeTaskBar = null;

private void ConfigurarIconeTaskBar()
{
    iconeTaskBar = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
    Stream iconStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new      Uri("pack://application:,,,/IMG;component/Imagens/locationICO.ico")).Stream;
    iconeTaskBar.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(iconStream);
    iconeTaskBar.DoubleClick += iconeTaskBar_DoubleClick;
    iconeTaskBar.Text = "IMG";
    iconeTaskBar.MouseDown += new   System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(iconeTaskBar_MouseDown);
}

private void iconeTaskBar_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();

        MenuItem menuItemVouPara = new MenuItem() { Header = "Cadastrar saída" };
        menuItemVouPara.Click += menuItemVouPara_Click;
        menuItemVouPara.Icon = new System.Windows.Controls.Image
        { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Imagens/voupara.png", UriKind.Absolute)) };

        menu.Items.Add(menuItemVouPara);

        menu.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: TrayIcon com WPF? Que api está usando?

Comment: Nenhuma, fiz com c# usando referência ao `TrayIcon` do windows Forms.

Comment: @ramaral, fiz mais ou menos assim como esta neste site --> https://ebbypeter.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/minimize-a-wpf-application-to-system-tray-in-c/

Comment: Se você está a usar um *System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu()* e depois o associa ao *NotifyIcon* através de `NotifyIcon.ContextMenu`, o *ContextMenu* deveria fechar por ele.

Comment: @ramaral, adicionei o código na pergunta, de como estou a fazer para criar o menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Julgo que o problema reside no facto de ser você a abrir o *Menu*.

A abertura do menu deve ser feita pelo [NotifyIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Depois de construir o menu deve associá-lo a ele através da propriedade *ContextMenu*.
Fazendo assim o *NotifyIcon* abrirá o Menu quando clicar com o botão do lado direito do rato sobre o icon.

O código seguinte cria um icon na *Task Bar* que apresentará um menu com o item *Cadastrar saída*. O icon desaparecerá quando a *Form* for fechada.

Se necessitar que o menu se adapte em função do estado(contexto) da aplicação, use o *ContextMenu.Popup Event* para construir os itens do menu.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon iconeTaskBar;
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ConfigurarIconeTaskBar();
    }

    private void ConfigurarIconeTaskBar()
    {
        components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();

        //Use o construtor System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(IContainer) para eliminar
        // a instância do NotifyIcon quando a Form é fechada. 
        iconeTaskBar = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(components);
        iconeTaskBar.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(@"C:\Windows\System32\PerfCenterCpl.ico");
        iconeTaskBar.Text = "IMG";

        //Crie um Menu
        var menu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
        //Crie MenuItems
        var menuItemVouPara = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem() {Text = "Cadastrar saída"};
       //Associe o Click event
        menuItemVouPara.Click += menuItemVouPara_Click;
       //associo-o ao Menu
        menu.MenuItems.Add(menuItemVouPara);

        //Associe esse menu à propeiedade ContextMenu do NotifyIcon
        iconeTaskBar.ContextMenu = menu;
        //Torne o NotifyIcon visível
        iconeTaskBar.Visible = true;
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Faça o Dispose do IContainer que passou no contrutor de NotifyIcon.
        // A instância de NotifyIcon será eliminada quando garbage collection libertar o Container
        if (components != null)
            components.Dispose();
        base.OnClosed(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, funciono certinho, tem como eu colocar uma imagem em cada item do menu?

Comment: Em vez da classe `System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu` use [System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) depois use `iconeTaskBar.ContextMenuStrip = menu;`

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10671895/2556111) no SOen.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!